# .screenrc: Escape a single quote

Tags: gnu-screen

escape ^\' gives me this error:

.screenrc: Missing ' quote.

How can I escape a single quote, so that C-' (rather than C-a) can be my screen escape key?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work: `escape "^''"`

But I can't test it on my system since <kbd>^'</kbd> in a terminal seems to be sent as a plain <kbd>'</kbd> to the underlying process.